# Aligning Text Left Above Div Below

Tags: html, css

I have two iframes displayed.  Above the iframes, I would like to insert a description of each one.  I am able to get the description A aligned over the iframe below, but I am not able to line up Description B directly over the left edge of the second iframe.

```css
.wrap {
 display: flex;
}

.wrapIn {
 flex: 1;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.guidedQueryHeading {
 font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description A:</div>
  <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description B:</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-xl-1 col-xl-10 wrapIn">
          <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="25%" align="left" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;" scrolling="auto" height="600" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="60%" align="right" height="600" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: flex` you can create easy column/row setup and align elements where you want to. Quick example using your elements below.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  width:50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.guidedQueryHeading {
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<div class="offset-xl-1 col-xl-10 row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1">Description A:</div>
        <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" scrolling="auto" height="600" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description B:</div>
        <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" align="right" height="600" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap each description and corresponding iframe in seperate divs, and then put those in your row div with display: flex, as such:

```css
    html,body{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    iframe{
      width: auto;
    }

    .iframe-element{
      margin: 10px;

    }

    .row {
      width: 100%;
        display: flex;

      flex-direction:row;
      align-items:center;
    }

    .guidedQueryHeading {
        font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 600;

        text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1.00);
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="iframe-element">
      <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description A:</div>
      <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="25%" align="left" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;" scrolling="auto" height="600" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe-element">
      <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description B:</div>
      <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="60%" align="right" height="600" allowfullscreen>     </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Justom add your new custom css as:***
**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
    }

    .wrapIn {
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;

    }
.custom{
    padding-right: 375px !important;
}

    .guidedQueryHeading {
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1.00);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn">Description A:</div>
    <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-1 wrapIn custom">Description B:</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-xl-1 col-xl-10 wrapIn">
      <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="25%" align="left" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;" scrolling="auto" height="600" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
      <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="60%" align="right" height="600" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  While this seems like the quickest/easiest solution to implement, one thing I do want to maintain is dealing with different screen sizes.  If you go into a non-maximized view, you'll notice that it no longer lines up above the iframe for Description B.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use "flex-grow" that help you easily to adjust items.

```css
.wrap {
 display: flex;
}

.wrapIn {
 flex: 1;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.guidedQueryHeading {
 font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1.00);
}

.item1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.item2 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn item1">Description A:</div>
  <div class="guidedQueryHeading col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 wrapIn item2">Description B:</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-xl-1 col-xl-10 wrapIn">
          <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="25%" align="left" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;" scrolling="auto" height="600" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="60%" align="right" height="600" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is something I tried and it seemingly worked for my application.  However, one thing I neglected to mention is that I would like this to work on various sized screens and even mobile applications.  The flex-grow seems to vary based on different screen sizes unfortunately.  Thanks again.